# How to split this string to array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I have string (from a file):

```
    [\x22thanh\x22,
        [[\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E nien\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],
        [\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E ca\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],
        [\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E nhan\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],
        [\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E thao\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]]
    ]
```

I saved this string to a variable name "s". I want split all strings betwen "[\x22" and "\x22," then save to an array named "s2". How I can do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: @TuyenTk What result do you expect?

Comment: I want a array like this: s2[0] = thanh; s2[1] = thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E nien\\u003C\\/b\\u003E;...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string s = @"[\x22thanh\x22,
    [[\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E nien\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],
    [\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E ca\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],
    [\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E nhan\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],
    [\x22thanh\\u003Cb\\u003E thao\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]]
]";
        string start = @"[\x22";
        string end = @"\x22";
        int pos = -1;

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        while ((pos = s.IndexOf(start)) > -1)
        {
            s = s.Substring(pos + start.Length);
            if ((pos = s.IndexOf(end)) > -1)
            {
                list.Add(s.Substring(0, pos));
                s = s.Substring(pos + end.Length);
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        string[] s2 = list.ToArray();
```

**EDIT**

Same result using `Split`:

```
  string[] s2 = s.Split(new string[] { @"[\x22" }, 
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(i => i.Substring(0, i.IndexOf(@"\x22")))
                 .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do as following :

```
var myArray = myString.Split("[\x22");
```

Do you want to remove the last characters aswell?

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] s2 = s.Split(new string[] {@"[\x22", @"\x22"}, 
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: +1 for using the useful `Split` overload, saving other hackery.

Comment: but I think you might also need to split on `"[[\x22"`, and probably `" ", ","`.

Comment: Thanks, and I know it might not be perfectly working solution (I think  OP would also have to remove new lines etc), but it's answer to the question: "I want split all strings betwen "[\x22" and "\x22," then save to an array named "s2"." The other stuff wasn't so clear so I didn't try to it (especially because I didn't fully understand question)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the position of first \x22 and next \x22 string. Next, you  should copy the text beetween that position. You can get position using `IndexOf` method.